# What is the meaning of “chiefly dialect”?

Tags: meaning, terminology

I was researching the synonyms of a particular phrase and I noticed the website had a tag on some words in square brackets: ***[chiefly dialect]***. On some words it had just ***[dialect]***.

This is something I’ve never seen before and I do not quite understand the distinction between the two nor the actual definition of “chiefly dialect”. I’ve attached a screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Chiefly means mostly, usually, on the whole, for the most part. Thus, not usually considered standard except in a few places or times.

Answer (score 2):

[Dialect](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dialect) is language use particular to a region (or group):

> a regional variety of language distinguished by features of vocabulary, grammar, and pronunciation from other regional varieties

A word can have a general meaning in a language and an additional or nuanced meaning in a regional dialect. For example, [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/is-boughten-a-word) themselves explain the meaning of "*chiefly dialect*":

> "chiefly dialect," which means that it mostly appears in regional varieties of English.

The dictionary lists all known meanings and uses of a word and marks regional ones as such. "*Chiefly dialect*" shows the meaning is somewhat limited to a region (but may have travelled or become more common elsewhere) and "*dialect*" means that the word has the given meaning only in a regional variety of the language.

"[*Chiefly*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chiefly)" means "mostly" or "mainly".

Comment: Don't you think "d"  is important in your reference? (d: a variety of language whose identity is fixed by a factor other than geography (such as social class))  For instance, as concerns  "anyways", do educated people use  it  generally in the regions where it is found?

Comment: Educated people (especially, *politicians*) are often inclined to include dialectal / "folksy" elements in their language because they think it helps connect them with voters and others whose approval they seek. ***Leastways***, that's my two penn'orth. But I'll just add that to my ear, ***leastways*** is simply "informal", whereas ***leastway*** sounds seriously dialectal (I don't know why that position reverses with ***anyway / anyways***).